# Best model for handling commands between Player1 and Player2

Tags: c++, design-patterns, network-programming, structure

I'm having trouble wrapping my head around this, and I apologize if this question isn't very clear. But I'll try.

For the sake of this post, I'll simply my problem a bit. I'm writing a game of multiplayer Tic Tac Toe (not really, but it's close enough to count). There are only three actions any given player can make:

1. The current player is allowed to place a marker.
2. Either player is allowed to request an Undo. The other player can choose to allow or deny the request.
3. Either player is allowed to Resign.

I wrote a GameEngine class that keeps track of the game board, checks the validity of marker placement, and win conditions. I would like to write Player classes, such as TerminalPlayer (to play the game from a command line), NetworkPlayer (to accept moves from a server), and ArtificialPlayer (to make it play offline).

My problem is this: given that each Player can send commands at any time (placeMarker, requestUndo, Resign), how do I structure this game?

I can think of solutions that might work (put each player in a thread, and have the GameEngine monitor requests), but everything I come up with is so clunky and awkward. I feel like there should be a good pattern for this, but I can't find it.

Specifically, can you answer:

1. What is the pattern that solves this problem? Does one exist, or is this more simple than I'm making it?
2. If a Boost library (or something like it) has solved this problem elegantly, what's the name of that library?

Comment: What is the interface through which the players can communicate through?

Comment: @jozefg, I assume you're talking about the interface to the game engine, not the GUI? There isn't any interface right now. That's what I'm struggling to write. In other words, how does the GameEngine manage input from two players?

Comment: If there's no latency between the two players (I.E. you're playing the simultaneously on the same machine) then you simply poll both player's inputs.  If either of the players change the gamestate then the act of changing the gamestate can invalidate the other player's input until the next polling time.

Don't try to poll input in parallel.  Just update player 1, check if the gamestate should switch, then repeat for the next player.

Comment: @JonG., there will be latency, but maybe that's okay. So you're suggesting that each player is in their own thread, and the GameEngine polls shared data?

Comment: I wouldn't bother with threads at all for something like this.  If latency is a problem you'll either need to timestamp the player's commands, or "statestamp" them from the state they were issued in.  If you receive input from a player from a state that is no longer valid then you can throw it out.  Your network polling could be threaded, but your input polling could simply be on the main thread and process all local commands + currently received commands synchronized just prior to polling.

Comment: But if I'm waiting for TerminalPlayer to enter a command, how do I also process commands that come from a NetworkPlayer? Do I use Ncurses (or something) to prevent TerminalPlayer from ever fully waiting around for input?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a simple [state machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine) would let you manage the game.

Comment: Yes, but I'm concerned about how the players can both send input to the game at once. A state machine will accept a command to go to a new state, but how does that command get there to begin with? Is each player operating in a separate thread?

Answer (score 0):

When some input is recieved to the server, you need to validate, based on the game rules, and decide weather to execute the input or discard it. As mentioned by Esteban, the game state would progress as a state machine, including state on which player is currently expected to take a turn.

Different pieces of input will be allowed at different states of the game,

If the possible states are:

- Player 1 Turn
- Player 2 Turn
- Player 1 Request Pending
- Player 2 Request Pending
- Game Over

Then you have a list of actions, when they are allowed, and how they change the state.

**Player 1 make turn:**

Allowed states: Player 1 turn

New State: Player 2 turn

**Player 1 Request Undo:**

Allowed states: Player 1 turn

New State: Player 1 Request Pending

**Player 2 Deny Request:**

Allowed states: Player 1 request pending

New State: Player 1 Turn

**Player 2 Resign:**

Allowed states: ALL

New State: Game Over

If a player makes a move out of turn, simply discard it.

Answer (score 0):

The concept you are looking for is called a game loop.  The term is fairly Googleable for how generic it sounds.  It is a simple forever loop that checks for input, steps game state and redraws the screen.  For the network player I would probably run that in a separate thread and have it post events that the main game loop picks up.